# Running Javascript to load a certain component based on switch statement from within JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its a little tricky to explain so title probably isn't that clear but basically I am working on a ReactJS project where I have a parent component, and this component, will render other components but based on various props or states will determine what component gets loaded.

I am using a functional component and originally the if/switch statement logic above the parent component return method and then just put this variable inside the JSX within the parent component to render the child. However, this made it hard to maintain as its a fairly large parent component so wanted to make it more clear and found that you can run some javascript from within the JSX by using the `{() => {//do stuff here }}`

I've therefore got the following code within my JSX

```
function ParentComponent(props)
{
    return (
        <div className='my-container'>
            {
                    () => {

                        console.log("Crash Details being loaded");
                        if (selectedCrashGroup === null) {
                            switch (props.match.params.project_type) {
                                case "Android":
                                    return (
                                        <CrashSummary time_period={timePeriod}
                                            project_id={props.match.params.project_id}
                                            project_stats={projectStats}
                                            affected_files={affectedFiles}/>
                                    )
                            }
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <CrashGroupDetails refreshCrashGroupData={refreshCrashGroupData}
                                            crashGroup={selectedCrashGroup}
                                            project_id={props.match.params.project_id}
                                            handleUserAssignmentClick={handleUserAssignmentClick}
                                            projectMembers={projectMembers}
                                            selectedAssignmentDetails={selectedAssignmentDetails}
                                            projectType={props.match.params.project_type}
                                            comment_id={props.match.params.comment_id}/>
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, doing this the components being returned within this method the `CrashDetails` and `CrashSummary` doesn't get rendered nor does the console.log line get written.

Is what I am trying to do not possible, or if it is possible what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the if/switch statement, use ternary operator. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: yea i know about tertiary if statements, they'll be other stuff to come in, this is just the basics to get it working. thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are just defining a function , but never calling it.

Similar to your example, i have defined a function, but never called it. Thus the screen will be blank.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { 
        (() => <h1>Hello React</h1>)   /* HERE */
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now we need to call it .

```
<div className="App">
      { 
        (() => <h1>Hello React</h1>) ()   /* here */

      }
    </div>
```

**Better Approach**

```
export default function App() {

  // Defining a function
  const content = () => <h1>Hello React</h1> ;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { content() }
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cdn-cn5j2?file=/src/App.js)

`{() => {//do stuff here }}  vs { 1+ 2 // any expression}`

The difference is that latter one will be invoked immediately  where the prior one will create a function , but wont invoke it.

Comment: Thanks, that would mean the if statement logic would be before the parent component return method. This is what I had originally and wanted to avoid just calling a method/variable from within the JSX as it was difficult to find when debugging the code. I can't remember where I saw it but it looked like you can have a method within the JSX and it will automatically get triggered

Comment: umm.. Inside JSX, call to a method will happen only if  you call it explicitly or attach to a event listener . when the event happens, the callback method will be invoked.. :)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Not quite how I remembered but I guess I must have missed something, this has done what I was after